# How to maintain Swing design separated from classes to the code is easily converted to Android afterwards

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, swing

I am writting a program in Java using Swing and I want to have the logic as much as separated from the window design as possible in order to readapt it for android in the future.

For example, I want the program to retrieve data from mySQL, put it into a Jtable and display it within the contentPane. If I wanted to have the code for the Jtable written in a different class that creates it and inserts the data and aldo a method that returns the Jtable when called from the main class(design).. something like this:

Class where Jtable is (infoDisplayer):

```
public class InfoDisplayer {
    static JScrollPane getTablaPathsSummary(){  
    String[] pathsSummaryColumnNames = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith","Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe","Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black","Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White","Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown","Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}};

    JTable pathsSelectionTable = new JTable(data,pathsSummaryColumnNames);
    pathsSelectionTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    pathsSelectionTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane pathsSelectionTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(pathsSelectionTable);
    return pathsSelectionTableScrollPane;

}

}
```

Main class:

```
    getContentPane().add(InfoDisplayer.getTablaPathsSummary(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The problem I see with this implementation is that I cannot see/modify the table from the design as its returned from the external method getTablaPathsSummary()

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

since getTablaPathsSummary is external source and you don't have access to change, you can not go ahead with this code for android..